# numpy gradient different between array and matrix

Tags: python, numpy, gradient

I want to get matrix gradient,but the result is inconsistent

```
g = img[0:3, 0:3]
gy, gx = np.gradient(g)
print gy,gx

arr=np.array([[138, 144, 141],[134, 135, 132],[137, 135, 133]])
gy, gx = np.gradient(arr)
print gy,gx
```

the result is differernt

the datatype :matrix

gy=array([[252. , 247. , 247. ],   [127.5, 123.5, 124. ],   [  3. ,   0. ,   1. ]])

gx=array([[ 6. , 1.5, 253. ],   [  1. , 127. , 253. ],   [254. , 126. , 254. ]])

the datatype :array

gy=array([[-4. , -9. , -9. ],   [-0.5, -4.5, -4. ],   [ 3. ,  0. ,  1. ]])

gx=array([[ 6. , 1.5, -3. ],   [ 1. , -1. , -3. ],   [-2. , -2. , -2. ]])

Comment: We don't know the content of `img`. Try printing it out?

Comment: I have sovled my problem. Thank you for your concern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not actually a matrix vs array issue (though using `matrix` is a bad idea and it's likely to cause other problems). Your `img` is of a small dtype, probably `uint8`, and the calculations are overflowing. Convert it to float first:

```
np.gradient(g.astype(float))
```

Demo:

```
In [7]: arr=np.array([[138, 144, 141],[134, 135, 132],[137, 135, 133]])
In [8]: arr_uint8 = arr.astype('uint8')
In [9]: gx, gy = np.gradient(arr_uint8)
In [10]: gx
Out[10]: 
array([[ 252. ,  247. ,  247. ],
       [ 127.5,  123.5,  124. ],
       [   3. ,    0. ,    1. ]])
In [11]: arr_float = arr_uint8.astype(float)
In [12]: gx, gy = np.gradient(arr_float)
In [13]: gx
Out[13]: 
array([[-4. , -9. , -9. ],
       [-0.5, -4.5, -4. ],
       [ 3. ,  0. ,  1. ]])
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have always ignored this issue. It sovled my problem. Thank you very much